# Minimal polynomial of an algebraic element

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> We have to determine minimal polynomial over $\mathbb Q$ of element $1+2^\frac{1}{3}+4^\frac{1}{3}$.

Here is my work, please tell me where is the mistake:
 We want polynomial with rational coefficients so:
$x = 1+2^\frac{1}{3}+4^\frac{1}{3}$, as $2^\frac{1}{3}-1$ is not zero, we can multiply both sides with that to get:
$(2^\frac{1}{3}-1) x = 1$ so
$2^\frac{1}{3} x = x + 1$ which now we can multiply three times with himself getting:
$2 x^3 = x^3 + 3 x^2 + 3 x + 1$ which is
$x^3 - 3 x^2 - 3 x - 1 = 0$. As 1 and -1 are the only candidates for rational zeroes, we see that this is irreducible over $Q$, so, this shall be minimal polynomial.
The problem is : they get $x^3-6 x- 6$ and that is correct.... So, I am wondering where I made a mistake, not how they came to their solution.

Comment: $x^3-6x-6$ is the minpoly of $2^{1/3}+4^{1/3}$, not $1+2^{1/3}+4^{1/3}$.

Comment: Your reasoning is correct 100%, and they made a mistake because $X^3-6X-6$ is the minimal polynomial for $x-1$ not $x$

Comment: Thanks a lot, helped me....

Comment: I closed this as a duplicate even though I answered the target. This was because there were no other answers. But, to tell you the truth, I was looking for duplicates of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3913997/11619), found both of these, acted, and only then realized that I have answered the older one. If I would remember...