# Determine the minimal polynomial of $\alpha = 1 + 3^{1/3} + 9^{1/3}$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. What is $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Determine the minimal polynomial of $\alpha = 1 + 3^{1/3} + 9^{1/3}$
> over $\mathbb{Q}$. What is $[\mathbb{Q}(\alpha):\mathbb{Q}]$?

I tried to rearrange $\alpha$ in a way that $f(\alpha) = 0$ but can't figure out this part.
If I take $(a-1)^3 = (3^{1/3} + 3^{2/3})^3$, it doesn't end. I can't get rid of power of $1/3$.

I also tried $\alpha = (1+3^{1/3})^2 - 3^{1/3}$ but doesn't work either.

Is my approach wrong?

Comment: Looks like the methods from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/95918/11619) will work. Because I happened to answer that one I won't vote to close as a duplicate. The use of matrices is more general and applies as is to any $\Bbb{Q}$-linear combination of $1,\root3\of3,\root3\of9$. Also, some of the discussion there relies on Galois theory, something you may not have seen yet.

Comment: Also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3344267/11619).

Answer (score 3):

Here is a different take that does not rely on algebraic manipulations.

$\mathbb{Q}(3^{1/3})$ has degree $3$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, with basis $\{1, 3^{1/3},9^{1/3}\}$.

The minimal polynomial of $\alpha$ is the minimal polynomial of the linear transformation $x \mapsto \alpha x$. This polynomial  can be computed using its matrix with respect to the basis above:
$$
A
=
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 3 & 3  \\ 1 & 1 & 3  \\ 1 & 1 & 1  \end{pmatrix}
$$
The characteristic polynomial of this matrix is $x^3 - 3 x^2 - 6 x - 4$.
This polynomial is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ because it has degree $3$ but no rational root (*), and so is the minimal polynomial of $A$ and hence of $\alpha$. Therefore, $\alpha$ has degree $3$ and so $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)=\mathbb{Q}(3^{1/3})$.

(*) use the rational root theorem here.

Comment: Is there a specific theorem related to your solution?

Comment: @jun, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/849464/589

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$(\alpha-1)^3=(3^{1/3}+3^{2/3})^3$$

$$\implies\alpha^3-3\alpha^2+3\alpha-1=3+3^2+3(3^{1/3}\cdot3^{2/3})(\alpha-1)$$

Alternatively,

$$\alpha=\dfrac{(3^{1/3})^3-1}{3^{1/3}-1}$$

$$\iff3^{1/3}=?$$

Now take cube in both sides

Comment: Where is the part after Alternatively coming from?

Comment: @jun, $$a^3-1^3=(a-1)(a^2+a+1)$$

Comment: um..sorry.  The RHS on the second line..  is that coming from the RHS on the first line?

Comment: OH NVM. I got it